# Play 3 video with 20 MB each simultaneously in HTML

Tags: html, video, synchronization

I am trying to play 3 different video with same duration in single HTML page.
I create 3 video tag and java script for sync all 3 videos, it is sync and working fine for 10 sec video.

Now in my application requirement is to play 3 videos with 1 min duration.
So all 3 videos are not sync either due to buffering issue or any other.

Please help me if any one have solution/ plugins/ video player for this.

Comment: Why not make a single 1-minute video whose content (pixels) are the three videos combined as one video display? Have you used the **FFmpeg** video tool before?

Comment: Thanks @VC.One , i haven't used FFmpeg tool. I will try and get back.